# Era andata a scuola con i genitori e le due sorelle - possessive adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I know that it is usual to omit the definite article before a family member if it is singular, if it is not qualified by an adjective and if the possessive adjective is not "loro".

However, I have read the following sentence in a learning tool:

> Era andata a scuola con i genitori e le due sorelle.

Why are the possessive adjectives missing here? Is that usual? Would it also happen when the definite article is omitted (e.g., mia zia => zia)?

Comment: It's implicit in the sentence. "Era andata a scuola" is referred to HER. I genitori and le due sorelle, are related to the subject, it's obvious that they are related to her, the pronouns can be omitted. I never say "le sue due sorelle"  it sound like a useless repetition.

Comment: If you are saying that definite article is omitted, shouldn't your example be "mia zia => zia"?

Comment: @Charo yes, in a sentence like " ero andato a scuola con zia". It's curious, but speaking about myself i say "ero andato a scuola con i miei genitori" and it sound right, because if i say "ero andato a scuola con i genitori" i put a distance between me and them, so someone could ask "i genitori di chi?"

Comment: @Charo. OK. I was not sure how to express the simultaneous omissions of the two determinants ("la" and "mia") in that example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Treccani's *[Enciclopedia dell'Italiano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aggettivi-e-pronomi-possessivi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)* you can read:

> **6. La codifica del possesso in italiano**
>
> Come osservato nel § 2, la funzione principale dei possessivi è quella
>   di codificare una relazione di possesso. In italiano essa può essere
>   tuttavia espressa anche in altri modi, senza l’uso dei possessivi.
>
> Innanzitutto, **l’italiano ammette l’omissione dell’aggettivo possessivo
>   quando l’individuazione del possessore è ovvia anche senza la sua
>   codifica esplicita** (cfr. Serianni 1988: 232; si veda anche Brunet
>   1980: 157-159):
>
> (52) ho lasciato l’auto in doppia fila [l’auto = «la mia auto»]
>
> (53) come stanno i figli? [i figli = «i tuoi/suoi figli»]
>
> Se da un lato in frasi come (52-53) il possessivo è facoltativo,
>   dall’altro la sua realizzazione è totalmente esclusa qualora venga
>   utilizzato un pronome intensivo in casi in cui ci si riferisca a parti
>   del corpo, come in (54-55); per estensione, l’uso di pronomi intensivi
>   determina l’impossibilità di utilizzare il possessivo anche quando il
>   nome non si riferisce a una parte del corpo, come in (56):
>
> (54) Marco si gratta la testa ~ *Marco (si) gratta la sua testa
>
> (55) non ti mangiare le unghie ~ *non (ti) mangiare le tue unghie
>
> (56) mi hanno rubato la macchina / hanno rubato la mia macchina ~ *mi
>   hanno rubato la mia macchina
>
> (57) gli è svenuta tra le braccia [= «è svenuta tra le sue (di lui)
>   braccia»].

So in Italian you can omit the possessive adjective when you can implicitly tell who is the possessor.
You could rewrite your sentence as it follows:

> Era andata a scuola con i *suoi* genitori e le *sue* due sorelle.

but it would sound as a unnecessary redundancy.

In the case of the article you can have a look to the question *[Uso dell'articolo e dell'aggettivo possessivo coi nomi di parentela](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/uso-dellarticolo-dellaggettivo-possessivo-no)* coming from Accademia della Crusca, where you can read when it is requested:

> L'articolo è però necessario in alcuni casi:
>
> - con le forme alterate, ad esempio "la mia sorellina", "il mio    nonnino", ecc. ed anche con le forme patrigno, matrigna, figliastro,
>     figliastra;
> - con i termini che indicano rapporti sentimentali ma non ancora di    parentela vera e propria, come ad esempio "il mio fidanzato", "la mia 
>     ragazza" e con essi anche tutte le varianti regionali (bello, bella,
>     moroso, morosa, amante, ecc.);
> - in frasi con accentuato valore enfatico, nelle quali, normalmente, il    possessivo viene posposto: *"il figlio mio"*, *"il nonno mio"*;
> - nei casi in cui il singenionimo è accompaganto da un antroponimo    (nome di persona o cognome) l'articolo, frequentemente, viene
>     omesso."

Comment: I think that the question about the article is if you may also omit the possessive in sentences such as "era andata con sua zia".

Comment: In this case you can also say _era andata con la zia_.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is what the OP is asking in his last question.